# "Could not find a declaration file for module" when using Workspaces and TypeScript Project References, only on VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using PNPM workspaces, TypeScript with Project References and VSCode.

My project builds fine (TypeScript compiles without any errors), but VSCode has issues finding type definitions for *some* of my own packages, even after they are built.

For example:

1. `packages/mypub/src/index.ts` exports `MyPub`
2. `packages/mypub/package.json` package is named `mypub`
3. `packages/mypub/tsconfig.json` defines `compilerOptions.composite` as true
4. `packages/fastify/tsconfig.json` defines `references` as `[{ "path": "../mypub" }]`
5. `packages/fastify/src/myPubPlugin.ts` imports `import { MyPub } from "mypub";`

VSCode says:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'mypub'. '/Users/wes/Developer/MyPub/packages/mypub/dist/index.cjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/mypub` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'mypub';`ts(7016)
```

But TypeScript checks and compiles it fine.

The full source files are on GitHub:

- [packages/mypub](https://github.com/WesSouza/MyPub/tree/main/packages/mypub)
- [packages/fastify](https://github.com/WesSouza/MyPub/tree/main/packages/fastify)

I'm going insane, what did I do that broke VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was caused by the Astro extension. Disabling it fixes the problem.

Tracking the issue on https://github.com/withastro/language-tools/issues/462.